# How do I clear a reported TeamCity service message build statistic?

Tags: build, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I have a build configuration that is running code coverage on unit tests using TeamCity's built-in dotCover tool. Then another runner runs code coverage on some API tests using a non-supported tool. I am currently reporting the coverage stats to TeamCity using the service messages:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='CodeCoverageAbsLTotal' value='$totalLines']"
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='CodeCoverageAbsLCovered' value='$totalLinesCovered']"
```

Everything works great. However, the first runner reports other statistics (Methods, Classes, Branches) on the unit tests and coverage it ran that I want cleared (I don't want any stats from the unit tests). How do I clear a build statistic that is already reported?

I tried using a similar message as above and setting `value=''` or `value='0'`. The `value=''` threw an java error that it couldn't parse, while `value='0'` had no effect on removing the statistic.

How do I clear a build statistic? Or just make dotCover not report any code-coverage stats?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-47322 has some remarks by JetBrains about the value 0 being basically ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Makes sense why `value='0'` had no effect.